# Weight painting mass distribution?

Tags: physics

Does anyone know if it's possible to use weight painting to distribute mass within a mesh for physics simulation purposes?  Like say I had a uniform mesh pole and I wanted to adjust the weight of one end vs. the other without changing the dimensions of the mesh at all. I'm just getting starting to get to grips with physics simulations, so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious. One idea I had would be to weight paint and then use the weights to distribute instances of a weight-bearing particle at different points on the mesh, but my gut says that it should be simpler than that.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rigid body simulation can’t be adjusted by weight painting but you can get pretty much the same effect by moving the centre of gravity by changing the Origin on the object. This will have the effect of making the object behave the same as if the weight was redistributed.

Comment: Thanks, Rich.  I had discovered the trick of moving the cursor around to represent the center of mass.  Just wondered if there was a way with weight painting, since it would have facilitated an animation I had in mind.  But if it can't be done, fair enough.